# angular injecting object data to dialog box

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-scope, angular5

I am trying to inject a angular-material dialog box with object data to show in a word-cloud.

Word-tag-cloud: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-tag-cloud-module

I have 2 components on the same page here:

**Main component:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'about',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: './about.html',
    styleUrls: ['./about.scss']
})

export class MainComponent {
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}
wordcloud(){
    this.dialog.open(CloudTest, {
        data: 
            {text: 'Stock prices', weight: 8, link: 'https://google.com', color: '#ffaaee'}
       });
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'about',
    styleUrls: ['./about.scss'],
    template: '<div><angular-tag-cloud [data]="data" [width]="options.width" [height]="options.height" [overflow]="options.overflow"> </angular-tag-cloud></div>'
  })
  export class CloudTest {
    constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: CloudData[] = []) {}
    options: CloudOptions = {
        // if width is between 0 and 1 it will be set to the size of the upper element multiplied by the value 
        width : 1000,
        height : 400,
        overflow: false,
    }
}
```

**On my HTML side:**

```
<button (click)="wordcloud()">Fuzzy Test</button>
```

**The error:**

```
core.js:1448 ERROR TypeError: this._dataArr.sort is not a function
    at TagCloudComponent.drawWordCloud (angular-tag-cloud-module.js:110)
    at TagCloudComponent.reDraw (angular-tag-cloud-module.js:90)
    at TagCloudComponent.ngOnChanges (angular-tag-cloud-module.js:44)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12361)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13889)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13832)
    at prodCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14556)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (CloudTest.ngfactory.js:25)
    at Object.updateDirectives (core.js:14278)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13798)
```

Another option i can do is to have `data: CloudData[] = []` in the second component, and push to this array from my `wordcloud()` function, but I'm not sure how to access that array since it is in a separate component / class.

Comment: check the documentation and examples out here: https://github.com/zeeshanhyder/angular-tag-cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass this as data:

```
data: 
   {text: 'Stock prices', weight: 8, link: 'https://google.com', color: '#ffaaee'}
```

So, this is an object.

And you expect to get this as data:

```
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: CloudData[]
```

That doesn't match. If you want an array, you need to pass an array:

```
data: [
   {text: 'Stock prices', weight: 8, link: 'https://google.com', color: '#ffaaee'}
]
```

Comment: In the documentation example the writer suggests: 
`data: CloudData[] = [
    { text: 'Initial Data weight-10', weight: 10 }
    // ...
  ];`

Comment: And that's precisely what I'm telling you to do. Pass an array, not an object as data to your dialog.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you so much. I had actually tried the array around the data before, but without the {} and it did not work

Comment: @KyleBurkett sorry